# Delete Duplicates per Account NO in SQL Server Manager

Tags: duplicates, sql-delete

I have a table called CAL (is a table that holds notes per customer account).  At some point an import process added 265 duplicates notes per acct_no, where i need to delete all but 1 per acct_no.

I am able to pull the query to find the duplicates but don't know how to delete duplicates per acct_No while keeping at least 1 record per acct_no

```
SELECT ACCT_NO, [TYPE], DATE_ADDED, TIME_ADDED, ADDED_BY, NOTES, COUNT(*)
FROM PLSHARED.DBO.CAL
GROUP BY ACCT_NO, [TYPE], DATE_ADDED, TIME_ADDED, ADDED_BY, NOTES
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
ORDER BY ACCT_NO
```

Sample Results are:
ACCT_NO TYPE        TIME_ADDED  ADDED_BY    NOTES   COUNT
100224              ~APPAACOLC  2019-04-23  11:35:00    APPAA       phone : 6463736300 result : LEFT MESSAGE    265
100299              ~APPAACOLC  2019-04-23  11:36:00    APPAA       phone : 6462793975 result : ANSWERED    265
100361              ~APPAACOLC  2019-04-23  11:35:00    APPAA       phone : 9178863391 result : ANSWERED    265
100630              ~APPAACOLC  2019-04-23  11:36:00    APPAA       phone : 5164663631 result : LEFT MESSAGE  phone : 5166623996 result : ANSWERED  265
101546              ~APPAACOLC  2019-04-23  11:37:00    APPAA       phone : 5163651466 result : ANSWERED    265
101809              ~APPAACOLC  2019-04-23  11:37:00    APPAA       phone : 9176985008 result : ANSWERED    265
102239              ~APPAACOLC  2019-04-23  11:37:00    APPAA       phone : 9174406128 result : LEFT MESSAGE    265

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, here is the proper code:

```
WITH Duplicates_CTE(ACCT_NO, [TYPE], DATE_ADDED, TIME_ADDED, ADDED_BY, NOTES, U_INVNO, recno)
AS
(
 SELECT ACCT_NO, [TYPE], DATE_ADDED, TIME_ADDED, ADDED_BY, NOTES, U_INVNO,Min(recno) recno
 FROM PLSHARED.DBO.cal
 GROUP BY ACCT_NO, [TYPE], DATE_ADDED, TIME_ADDED, ADDED_BY, NOTES,U_INVNO
 HAVING Count(*) > 3)

DELETE FROM PLSHARED.DBO.cal
WHERE recno IN (
 SELECT cal.recno
 FROM PLSHARED.DBO.cal
 INNER JOIN Duplicates_CTE
 ON cal.ACCT_NO = Duplicates_CTE.ACCT_NO
 and cal.[TYPE] = Duplicates_CTE.[TYPE]
 and cal.DATE_ADDED = Duplicates_CTE.DATE_ADDED
 and cal.TIME_ADDED = Duplicates_CTE.TIME_ADDED
 and cal.ADDED_BY = Duplicates_CTE.ADDED_BY
 and cal.NOTES = Duplicates_CTE.NOTES
 and cal.U_INVNO = Duplicates_CTE.U_INVNO
 AND cal.recno <> Duplicates_CTE.recno
)
```